# Add/substract timedelta to imported time

Tags: python

I am importing two time values (format "%H:%M:%S") into this function and I would like to add/subtract a buffer (check_period, usually a value of 5) to it. The timedelta works fine on the time values created in this function, but not for imported values. Any suggestions on how I can fix this?

Many thanks,

VBA Pete

```
def check_shuttertime(close_time,open_time,check_period):

    neg_adj_current_time = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(hours=0, minutes=check_period+1)
    neg_adj_current_time = neg_adj_current_time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    pos_adj_current_time = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(hours=0, minutes=check_period+1)
    pos_adj_current_time = pos_adj_current_time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    close_time = close_time + datetime.timedelta(hours=0, minutes=check_period+1) #<-ERRROR OCCURS HERE
    open_time = open_time - datetime.timedelta(hours=0, minutes=check_period+1) #<-ERRROR OCCURS HERE
    current_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: What `close_time` and `open_time` are you trying with?

Comment: What's the error?  Without that, I'd have to guess that `close_time` and `open_time` are strings but they need to be of type `datetime.datetime`.

Comment: What do you mean by "imported values"? Please post a [mre] that reproduces your problem.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: First check if `close_time` is `datetime` object - `print( type(close_time) )`. If it is string then first you have to convert it to `datetime` - ie using `strptime` (`String Parse Time`). BTW: if you want to use later these values then better keep them as `datetime` instead of using `.strftime("%H:%M:%S")`

Comment: @furas: Thanks for the feedback, that help resolving my issue. I was mixing string and timedate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If close_time and open_time are of type strings you will get an error stating that the + operator between a string and timedelta is not supported:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "datetime.timedelta") to str
```

The way to fix this would be to parse the string into a datetime before applying the addition. E.g. as follows:

```
import datetime
close_time="11:22:33"
new_close_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(close_time, "%H:%M:%S") + datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)
print(new_close_time)
```

This would then yield:

```
1900-01-01 11:27:33
```